# Zabbix4.2 how to moniter a directory size

Tags: zabbix

I try to add an item like `vfs.dir.size["/root/test",,,,,],` but it doesn't work.

*ex. Error*
[image: Error - Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. firstly - your item only needs to be short as so: `vfs.dir.size["/root/test"]`
2. secondly - please verify that user `zabbix` has access to `/root/test` directory as I assume it does not.

Zabbix can only monitor what user `zabbix` has access to on the system.